# colocar um div dentro de uma funcao no php

Tags: php, css, div, yii2

Tenho esse comando que faz a verificação no banco de dados e verifica se o usuário está bloqueado, em caso positivo mostra uma mensagem de erro, se não estiver bloqueado ele continua a execução normal. 
O que estou querendo é quando ele fizer a verificação mudar a mensagem de erro para uma caixa, que quando o usuário clicar no botão login e se ele estiver bloqueado vai aparecer essa caixa.

Segue o codigo da "caixa":

```
<div id="mod-danger" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="modal fade">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" class="close"><span class="mdi mdi-close"></span></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <div class="text-danger"><span class="modal-main-icon mdi mdi-close-circle-o"></span></div>
                        <h3>Atenção!</h3>
                        <p><h1>Usuario Bloqueado</h1><br><h2>PorFavor contatar algum adm para resolver.</h2></p>
                        <div class="xs-mt-50">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer"></div>
                </div>
                </div>

</div>
```

e quero colocar essa div nessa funcao onde ele verifica o bloqueio

```
public function bloqueado(){
    $model = self::findByUsuLogin($this->usu_login);


    if ($model->usu_block){
         $this->addError('usu_login', "Usuario Bloqueado, por favor entrar em contato com algum adm.");
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

quero mudar a mensg de erro que aparece que é essa [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]  para essa tela com a mensg de erro [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

se alguem puder me ajudar eu ficaria agradecido.

Comment: Desculpa amigo, nao entendi muito bem sua pergunta, pode explicar um pouco melhor???? obrigado.

Comment: vc falou pra fazer o echo pra aparecer essa caixa no caso eu quero aquela caixa que coloquei no exemplo que e o primeiro codigo so coloco ela no echo seria isso?

Comment: Opa, li seu comentario e é isso mesmo, porque assim que a função for chamada ela irá chamar o modal e mostrar assim como quer.

Comment: uai, troca a linha da mensagem por `$("#mod-danger").modal('show');`

Comment: Marque a resposta como aceita, veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx7Ts.png e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 0):

Como não há elementos suficientes para reproduzir seu código, fiz com uma simples condicional para mostrar a tela de mensagem de erro

```js
    $model="bloqueado";
    
    if ($model=="bloqueado"){
         $("#mod-danger").modal('show');
        //return false;
    }else{
        //return true;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="mod-danger" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="modal fade">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
     <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
           <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" class="close"><span class="mdi mdi-close"></span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="text-center">
                <div class="text-danger"><span class="modal-main-icon mdi mdi-close-circle-o"></span></div>
                <h3>Atenção!</h3>
                <p><h1>Usuario Bloqueado</h1><br><h2>PorFavor contatar algum adm para resolver.</h2></p>
                <div class="xs-mt-50"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: deu certo vlw irmao